# How Do I Print a Blank Form in MS Access to be used for data collection in the field?

Tags: ms-access

I am leading a data collection initiative in which teams are sent out to remote areas in the field to collect data.  Its not possible to send the collection teams out with any kind of technology, so the data collection must be done using a paper and pencil only.

I have a MS Access database with forms set up for data entry.  Besides a screen capture, how can I print a blank form so that the data collectors can simply pencil in the values when they are in the field?

I've tried printing the form, but printing always shows entries from the database — I cannot find a way to print a blank copy of the form.

Comment: Screen capture is probably the easiest and fastest way to do this. Forms aren't meant to be printed in Access. The alternate is to create a report based on the control locations of the form, but unbound to any data source. That seems like a lot of work compared to the screen capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lybren offered some good solutions.  However, I ended up using Adobe Pro.  I printed as PDF, then deleted the text that way.

Alternatively, you could do this all within MS Access itself, just set the text color for all the fields to be the same as the background color when you print.

Answer (score 2):

Many solutions.

1. Create a form of the table, unbound the fields by deleting each control recordsource.
2. Create a report of a copy of the table. Fill the copy table with blank spaces.
3. Create an unbound form, arrange textboxes as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, these are all good options.  I ended up just printing as PDF then deleting the text using Adobe Pro.  I had required fields, so I couldn't save a  blank record, but your idea got me to thinking: just change the text color to be the same as the background color.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make the font in your data fields the same colour as the fields background. Quickest way I found!

Comment: It looks more like comment then an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)